# Spacing of vdots in a0poster class

Tags: spacing, posters

I'm having trouble with the spacing of the individual dots that are typeset by `\vdots` when using the a0poster class.  In particular, the dots are much closer together than the dots typeset by either `\cdots` or `\ddots`.  Does anyone know what causes this and how to fix it??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In plain they are defined as:

```
\def\ldots{\mathinner{\ldotp\ldotp\ldotp}} 
\def\cdots{\mathinner{\cdotp\cdotp\cdotp}} 
\def\vdots{\vbox{\baselineskip=4pt \lineskiplimit=0pt 
\kern6pt \hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}}} 
\def\ddots{\mathinner{\mkern1mu\raise7pt\vbox{\kern7pt\hbox{.}}\mkern2mu 
\raise4pt\hbox{.}\mkern2mu\raise1pt\hbox{.}\mkern1mu}}
```

Assuming LaTeX doesn't touch on these, my money's on the change of `\baselineskip` in the definition of `\vdots` for your problem.

As for a solution, I would suggest in this day and age of Unicode, to use a character devoted for that, namely ⋮ (22EE).

Comment: Thanks, this helped completely.  I ended up redefining `\vdots` but with a `\baselineskip` of 10pt.  It worked like a charm.