# Different spacing between \vdots, \ldots \cdots,and \ddots

Tags: macros, amsmath

Zooming in on my very simple code, I never have noticed that the dots that are usually put in the matrices have different spacings. The vertical dots seem closer to one another.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{pmatrix}
\ldots & 2 & 3\\
a & b & \vdots\\
5 & \ddots & 7
\end{pmatrix}\]
\end{document}
```

I have seen the code into this old question [Spacing of vdots in a0poster class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/spacing-of-vdots-in-a0poster-class) and there is a possible answer (peraphs) but it is defined in Plain TeX.

> But is it possible to use some patches (or originally change the LaTeX code of the dots) to have the dots with the same spacing, changing their distance as I like?

Comment: As it stands the question reads "Is it possible to patch the definitions?" The answer is trivial: of course. I guess you want more that that, right `:-)`

Comment: @campa I'm scarce :-( You are (and other users) very free to improved the title and any part of my question. You're welcome :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original definitions are found in `latex.ltx` and `fontmath.ltx`

```
% \ldots is \let to \dots
\DeclareRobustCommand{\dots}{\ifmmode\mathellipsis\else\textellipsis\fi}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ldotp}{\mathpunct}{letters}{"3A}
\def\mathellipsis{\mathinner{\ldotp\ldotp\ldotp}}

\DeclareRobustCommand
  \ddots{\mathinner{\mkern1mu\raise7\p@
    \vbox{\kern7\p@\hbox{.}}\mkern2mu
    \raise4\p@\hbox{.}\mkern2mu\raise\p@\hbox{.}\mkern1mu}}

\DeclareRobustCommand
  \vdots{\vbox{\baselineskip4\p@ \lineskiplimit\z@
    \kern6\p@\hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}}}
```

and the spacings are indeed quite different:

- `\ldots` (more exactly `\mathellipsis`) has three `\mathpunct` atoms, plus the natural width of the box (which is quite larger than the dot itself, see later);
- `\vdots` has `4pt`;
- `\ddots` has a strange mixture of hard lengths expressed in `pt` and flexible ones expressed in `mu`.

I can give a more-or-less heuristic patch; this is based on the observation that in CM from `10pt` to `12pt` the box containing the period has a width of roughly `3pt`, while the period itself is roughly `1pt` wide. (I stress it: roughly). Of course, hard-coding lengths in `pt` prevents the length from being homogeneous for any font size. You can of course tweak the parameters to your taste.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} % only for the matrix example

\makeatletter

\def\mathellipsis{\mathinner{{.}\kern2\p@{.}\kern2\p@{.}}}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\ddots}
   {
    \sbox0{.}
    \mathinner{
    \raise\dimexpr2.82\p@+.94\wd0\relax\copy0
    \kern\dimexpr1.41\p@-.19\wd0\relax
    \raise\dimexpr1.41\p@+.47\wd0\relax\copy0
    \kern\dimexpr1.41\p@-.19\wd0\relax
    \box0
    }
}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\vdots}
   {%
    \sbox0{.}%
    \vbox{%
      \offinterlineskip
      \kern2\p@ %<-- this makes the box somewhat higher (plain TeX and LaTeX have 4\p@) 
      \hbox{.}%
      \kern\dimexpr2\p@+.666\wd0\relax
      \hbox{.}%
      \kern\dimexpr2\p@+.666\wd0\relax
      \hbox{.}%
      }%
}

\makeatother

\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
   \begingroup
   \mathsurround=0pt
   \fboxrule=0.2pt
   \fboxsep=-0.2pt
   \fbox{$#1$}
   \sbox0{$#1$}(\the\wd0$\times$\the\ht0)
   \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

% original definition
$|\mathinner{\ldotp\ldotp\ldotp}|$

$|\ldots|$

\fboxrule=0.2pt
\fboxsep=-0.2pt
\mathsurround=0pt

12pt:
\fbox{$\vdots$}
\fbox{$\ldots$}
\fbox{$\ddots$}

11pt:
\small
\fbox{$\vdots$}
\fbox{$\ldots$}
\fbox{$\ddots$}

10pt:
\footnotesize
\fbox{$\vdots$}
\fbox{$\ldots$}
\fbox{$\ddots$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, these values will become utterly useless when another font is used.

Is it worth it? I don't think so.

Comment: Very kind campa I not know this. You're right absolutely. I not know that the original definitions are found in `latex.ltx` and `fontmath.ltx`. After 20 years I not know all the extensions of the file. Now I have understood the ltx files. Approved! Thank you very much.